# Can't load-file

Tags: file-io, clojure

I have the file male_female.clj in the following directory on Windows:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\vreinpa\My Documents\Books\ProgrammingClojure\code\src\examples
```

Before starting the REPL, I switch to that directory:

```
U:\>c:
C:\>cd C:\Documents and Settings\vreinpa\My Documents\Books\ProgrammingClojure\code\src\examples
```

I then start the REPL:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\vreinpa\My Documents\Books\ProgrammingClojure\code\src\examples>lein repl
Warning: classpath not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic classpath or change the name.
REPL started; server listening on localhost:13278.
```

I then try to load the file, but get the following error:

```
user=> (load-file "male_female.clj")
user=> FileNotFoundException male_female.clj (The system cannot find the file specified)   java.io.FileInputStream.open (:-2)
```

What am I doing wrong here? The file is definitely in the directory that I changed to before starting the REPL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you working with the [Programming Clojure repo](https://github.com/stuarthalloway/programming-clojure)? I just cloned it and tried the same thing (albeit on a Mac) and had the same error.

If you are, try running `lein repl` from the root of the Git repo and then use `(load "examples/male_female")`. You can then access the definitions in this file by switching to the namespace with `(in-ns 'examples.male-female)` or fully with the fully qualified name: `examples.male-female/m`, etc. This worked for for me.

I'm not sure where `load-file` looks, but I think `load` will look in the Java classpath. You can inspect the classpath from a Clojure REPL with `(System/getProperty "java.class.path")`.

*edit*

I experimented with it after reading the [docs](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/load-file) on `load-file` and found that this worked too: `(load-file "src/examples/male_female.clj")`, regardless of where I was in the project. This might be something to do with Leiningen and what it considers the project root.